# Offline Speech Recognition in qpython3

Tags: android, python, qpython, qpython3

I have been trying to make a qpython program that uses `sl4a.Android.recognizeSpeech` function. The functionality works fine online.

In my phone settings, I turned on and downloaded offline speech recognition and google now works fine offline, but the python speech does not work at all, asking me to try again every single time.

Sample Code:

```
import sl4a 
import time

droid = sl4a.Android()

def speak(text):
    droid.ttsSpeak(text)
    while droid.ttsIsSpeaking()[1] == True:
        time.sleep(1)

def listen():
    return droid.recognizeSpeech('Speak Now',None,None)

def login():
    speak('Passphrase, please')
    try:
        phrase = listen().result.lower()
    except:
        phrase = droid.dialogGetPassword('Passphrase').result
    print(phrase)
    if phrase == 'pork chops':
        speak('Welcome')
    else:
        speak('Access Denied')
        exit(0)

login()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
droid.recognizeSpeech("foo", None, None)
```

returns an Array with the recognized Speech in Index number 1. So if you want to access it, you have to type

```
return droid.recognizeSpeech("foo", None, None)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of the above worked for me. So I solved that this way:

```
x, result, error = droid.recognizeSpeech("Speak")
```

The result variable stores the speech recognized from the user

Example:

```
import sl4a
import time

droid = sl4a.Android()

def Speak(talk):
   try:
     droid.ttsSpeak(talk)
     while droid.ttsIsSpeaking()[1] == True:
           time.sleep(2)
   except:
     droid.ttsSpeak("nothing to say")

def listen():
   global result,error
   time.sleep(1)
   x, result, error = droid.recognizeSpeech("Speak")

while True:
   try:
     listen()
   except:
     print(error)

   try:
     if len(str(result)) > 0:
        print(result)
        if result == "how old are you":
           Speak("I'm 1 year old")
        elif result is None:
           break
        else:
           Speak("I heard " + result)
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     break
```