# Can I use the android module in python on windows

Tags: python, speech-recognition, qpython

Is there any way at all to use the android module on windows? I have been trying to make a speech recognition program on windows (which has been a tough thing since it has to work offline) and I noticed this: [Offline Speech Recognition in qpython3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683016/offline-speech-recognition-in-qpython3)

But that's qpython, and I need that module named 'android' from qpython somehow to be able to use this: http://mattfenlon.com/2010/11/14/sl4a-speech-recognition-and-transcription/

I tried pip install android, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Using modules, that rely on the Android API (like the android module) can't work on windows. Windows 10 has a Linux Subsystem, but no Android subsystem